# swap and move infinite recursion

Tags: c++, c++17, swap, move-semantics

I have a very simple example class, compiled with C++17.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct name {
    std::string first, middle, last;
    name() = default;
    name(name const&) = default;
    name(name &&) = default;

    name& operator=(name o) {
        std::swap(*this, o); // bad!
        return *this;
    }
};
int main() {
    name n1{"mr", "john", "smith"};
    name n2 = std::move(n1); 
    name n3 = n2;

    std::cout << n3.first << " " << n3.middle << " " << n3.last;
}
```

Using this value-semantics, bundled move assignment and I deliberately called qualified swap, instead of `using std::swap; swap(*this, o);`. I didn't provide my swap anyways. Thinking that STL implements swap as a move construction and series of move assignments, I thought this implementation would infinitely recurse, swap calling move and move calling swap. Is `std::swap` changed into member-wise swap or something like that?

Comment: Why are you declaring the constructors and assignment operator? All of these will be implicitly declared. See [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @Kerndog73 Yes, rule of zero is better. This is just to experiment with that bundled assignment operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never invoked `operator=`; all of your code is using [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) (which invokes constructors), specifically [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), not assignment (which invokes `operator=`).

Change the code to:

```
name n1{"mr", "john", "smith"};
name n2, n3;

n2 = std::move(n1); 
n3 = n2;
```

and you'll see your `operator=` used (and presumably explode).

Answer (score 2):

1. given you haven't defined your own `swap()`, writing `std::swap(*this, o);`, or `using std::swap; swap(*this, o);` is the same thing (within the frame of your code example) and really does not highlight the intention of such writing: in absence of ADL, the `std::swap` version would be used in both cases.
2. in your declarations:

   > ```
   > name n2 = std::move(n1); 
   > name n3 = n2;
   > ```

`operator=()` is never called, the initialization will be done only using your class constructors.